# Social Engine how to get big profile image?

Tags: socialengine

For displaying little avatar photos i use `$this->itemPhoto(_someID_, 'thumb.icon')`, so `'thumb.icon'` argument makes the method return small photo. What is the argument that would make SE4 return big user photo? Lack of documentation makes trivial things hard to figure out.

Comment: after days of research, I tried trial n' error method and got solution: `thumb.profile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research, I tried trial n' error method and got solution: `thumb.profile`
This will render user's profile picture.

Answer (score 5):

And if you need size of image large or small you do like this:

for large images:

```
thumb.image.large
```

for small images:

```
thumb.image.small
```